# Firebase - Previous account data still visible after signing in with second account

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an angular web app that uses firebase authentication and firestore. When signing in, the user will see a list of albums with the ability to add and delete. However, upon signing out, i'm returned to my login screen. If I sign in with my second account I presented with the list of albums from account one. I cannot add any as my security rules prevent it. If I refresh the page, the correct list of albums for account two appears.

I'm not entirely sure what can cause this? Is there extra work i need to put into the sign out method that ensures any immediate login to another account is 'fresh'?

```
  login(email: string, password: string) {
    this.errorMessage = "";
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(value => {
      if (this.authGuardService.authGuardStateURL != undefined) {
        this.router.navigate([this.authGuardService.authGuardStateURL]);
        this.fetchUserEmail();
        return of(true);
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['home']);
        this.fetchUserEmail();
        return of(true);
      }
    })
      .catch(err => {
        this.errorMessage = ErroAuthEn.convertMessage(err['code']);
        return of(false);
      });
  }
```

```
  signOut() {
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut().then(() => {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    })
  }
```

**Album Query**

Below is the query to fetch the list of albums from the firestore datebase. This snippet is within one of my services. It returns all albums that are situated underneath the signed in users ID. As you can see, the user_id is sent to this function so it can perform the correct query. This works perfectly fine. However, as mentioned above, if i sign out of account 1 into account 2, the results produced by this query will displayed account 1's details before a refresh...

**Note**: Whilst typing this it's made me realise that this function is called within a service on service load, rather than called from the component, therefore when a user signs out, that service won't be initiated again until a page refresh. I think this might be causing it. I will need to test.

```
getAlbums(user_id) {
   this.albumsCollection = this.afs.collection<album>(`users/${user_id}/albums`, ref => {
     return ref.orderBy('album_title');
   });
  this.albums = this.albumsCollection.valueChanges({ idField: 'id' });
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're seeing albums from the client-side Firestore cache initially, which isn't cleared when you sign the user out (since client-side Firestore has no knowledge of what user "owns" what data). It might help if we can see how you query the database.

Comment: This would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the response both. Updated the album query. This is within an album service that's called on component load.

Comment: Can you supply the updated snippet of code with comments so that we may offer further advice? What do you expect it to do and what is happening?